# How long does it take from the time you purchase licenses to have those licenses available to assign to users?

Tags: licenses, purchasing

The question is pretty straight forward. I bought some licenses yesterday and am still waiting for them to be available in my org. Is that normal? Are they usually available right away or does it take a day or two before they can be used? My rep said it would take a few hours, but it's been well over 12 hours by now.

Comment: An update on my particular case - apparently they have been provisioned I just can't see them for some reason - working with support right not to try and resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it take days.  Can depend on time of year (related to how close you are to the close of a quarter/month/etc.)
From what I understand there's a manual process that has to happen and humans get overloaded when all the sales folks are coming in all at the same time with signed contracts for more licenses.

Comment: Hmm, kind of surprising that there is still a strong human component to the process. Maybe someone should tell these guys about automating their sales process or something ;)

Comment: That's crazy talk sir! ;-)